# How to merge two faces by creating a third

Tags: edges, faces, properties

I'm very new at blender and sometimes I get stuck in stupid problems, but I want to know how to merge two faces by creating a third as a "bridge".

Here's a pic where I'm stuck 
[image: Image 1]
I want to merge these two selected edges by creating a face with the same dimensions of the one at bottom.

Here's what I want
[image: Image 2]
is it possible to do this without knowing the exact dimensions of the face at bottom? if not, how do I get the properties such as Dimension/Position/Angle of the selected face??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two-step solution:

1) Duplicate your face
*Mesh->Duplicate*
Shortcut: <kbd>Shift+D</kbd>

[image]

...and move it up
- use snapping options
- use orthographic view and side view to be more precise

[image]

2) Select your edges and connect them with a new face.
*Vertex->New Face*
Shortcut: <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]